# java ejb jsp unreported exception

Tags: java, jsp, ejb, javabeans

trying to use a jsp to interact with a bean however, get some errors when running it.

Here are the errors I see in the browser

Generated servlet error:
    [javac] C:\Sun\AppServerNew\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\j2ee-apps\ConverterApp\war-ic_war\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java:21: unreported exception javax.naming.NamingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac]       InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
                        ^

Generated servlet error:
    [javac] C:\Sun\AppServerNew\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\j2ee-apps\ConverterApp\war-ic_war\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java:22: unreported exception javax.naming.NamingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac]       Object objRef = ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/Converter");
                           ^

Generated servlet error:
    [javac] C:\Sun\AppServerNew\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\j2ee-apps\ConverterApp\war-ic_war\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java:24: unreported exception javax.ejb.CreateException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac]      converter = home.create();

index.jsp

```
<%@ page import="converter.Converter, converter.ConverterHome, java.math.*, javax.ejb.*, javax.naming.*, 
javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject, java.rmi.RemoteException" %>
<%!
  private Converter converter = null;
  public void jspInit() {
    try {
      InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
      Object objRef = ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/Converter");
      ConverterHome home = (ConverterHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(objRef, ConverterHome.class);
     converter = home.create();

    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    } 
  }
%>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Converter</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
<h1><center>Converter</center></h1>
<hr>
<p>Enter an amount to convert:</p>
<form method="get">
<input type="text" name="amount" size="25">
<br>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
<%
  String amount = request.getParameter("amount");
  if ( amount != null && amount.length() > 0 ) {
    BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal (amount);
%>
  <p><%= amount %> dollars are  
    <%= converter.dollarToYen(d) %>  Yen.
  <p><%= amount %> Yen are 
    <%= converter.yenToEuro(d) %>  Euro.
<%
   }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

ConverterBean

```
package converter;
import javax.ejb.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.rmi.*;

public class ConverterBean implements SessionBean {

BigDecimal yenRate = new BigDecimal("122.00");

BigDecimal euroRate = new BigDecimal("0.0077");


public BigDecimal dollarToYen(BigDecimal dollars) {
    BigDecimal result = dollars.multiply(yenRate);
    return result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
}

public BigDecimal yenToEuro(BigDecimal yen) {
    BigDecimal result = yen.multiply(euroRate);
    return result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
}

  public void ejbActivate(){}

  public void ejbPassivate(){}

  public void ejbRemove(){}

  public void ejbCreate(){}

  public void setSessionContext(SessionContext ctx){}



}
```

ConverterHome

```
package converter;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.ejb.*;

public interface ConverterHome extends EJBHome {

Converter create() throws CreateException, RemoteException;



}
```

Converter

```
package converter;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.ejb.*;
import java.math.*;

public interface Converter extends EJBObject{

public BigDecimal dollarToYen(BigDecimal dollars)
throws RemoteException;

public BigDecimal yenToEuro(BigDecimal dollars)
throws RemoteException;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `jspInit()` method in `index.jsp` to:

```
public void jspInit() {
    try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        Object objRef = ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/Converter");
        ConverterHome home = (ConverterHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(objRef, ConverterHome.class);
        converter = home.create();

    }catch(NamingException ne){
    }catch (RemoteException ex) {
    }catch(CreateException ce){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cacth `NamingException` and `CreateException` on ur `.jsp` file, after `RemoteException`.